# Append contents of .msg attachment to message body

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, msg

I have a script to open attachments and append them to the message body. I have it working for text documents but I need it working for .msg attachments too.

At the moment it just doesn't read the object. Can anyone help?

```
Sub RunAScriptRuleRoutine(MyMail As MailItem)

Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olMailAT As Outlook.MailItem

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

If olMail.Subject = "lala" Then

    If olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

        Dim strLine As String
        Dim mailLine As String
        Dim strLines As String

        For i = 1 To olMail.Attachments.Count

            strFileName = "C:\emailTemp\" + olMail.Attachments.Item(i).FileName

            If InStr(strFileName, "msg") Then

                olMail.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFileName
                strLines = strLines + "//Start of " + strFileName + " //" + vbCrLf

                Open strFileName For Input As #1
                    Do While Not EOF(1)
                    Line Input #1, strLine
                        mailLine = mailLine + strLine
                    Loop
                Close #1

                olMailAT = mailLine
                strLine = objMailAT.Body
                strLines = strLines + "heres the .msg" + vbCrLf
                strLines = strLines + "//End of " + strFileName + " //" + vbCrLf

            Else

                olMail.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFileName

                strLines = strLines + "//Start of " + strFileName + " //" + vbCrLf
                Open strFileName For Input As #1
                    Do While Not EOF(1)
                    Line Input #1, strLine
                        strLines = strLines + vbCrLf + strLine
                    Loop
                Close #1
                strLines = strLines + "//End of " + strFileName + " //" + vbCrLf

            End If

        Next

        'save to email body and save email
        olMail.Body = strLines
        olMail.Save

    End If

End If

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/).

Also, you should look at this documentation for format specificaion
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To read the contents of a .msg file, I have used the following approach.

1. Use CreateItemFromTemplate for the msg file using the Outlook object
2. Use this Outlook object to save the data into a .txt file
3. Once the .txt file is created, read it and use the data as required

```vb
Dim OL : Set OL=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim Msg ':Set Msg= CreateObject("Outlook.MailItem")
Set Msg = OL.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\test.msg")
'MsgBox Msg.Subject
Msg.saveAs "C:\test.txt", olDoc
'The above statement will save the contents of .msg 
'file into the designate .txt file
Set OL = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing
```

Once the .txt file is created use it as required for your computations.

Answer (score 0):

By the way...for a full solution see here... http://www.geakeit.co.uk/2010/06/25/automating-email-feedback-loop-fbl-processing-and-getting-around-aol%E2%80%99s-recipient-email-address-issue/

Answer (score 0):

```
    Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
     Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
     Set objApp = Application
     On Error Resume Next
     Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
     Case "Explorer"
     Set GetCurrentItem = _
     objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
     Case "Inspector"
     Set GetCurrentItem = _
     objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
     Case Else
     End Select
    End Function
 'This is how you read the attachment using your path "strFileName"
   Set OL = New Outlook.Application
   Set myMessage = OL.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFileName)
   myMessage.Display
   Set msg2 = GetCurrentItem()
   MsgBox(msg2.Body)
   mg2.Close 1
```